# How to set value in Object

Tags: javascript, object, data-structures, ecmascript-5

I have to set value in object.

This is the problem: when I try to write a prop in object that has some props, previous props will be deleted.

I solved two cases and there's the last one.
I need test2 to be saved.
How can I fix it?

Thanks.

```js
var obj = {
  keyOne: "foo",
  keyTwo: {
    test1: "baz",
    test2: {
      test21: ["bar"],
    }
  }
}

function setObjectProperty(obj, string, value) {
  var path = string.split('.');
  var currentObj = obj;
  for (var i = 0; i < path.length - 1; i++) {
    if (!currentObj[path[i]] || currentObj[path[i]] != "string") {
      currentObj[path[i]] = {};
      currentObj = currentObj[path[i]];
    }
  }
  currentObj[path[path.length - 1]] = value;
};

setObjectProperty(obj, 'keyOne', 'new');
setObjectProperty(obj, 'keyOne.key.key2', 'newnew');
setObjectProperty(obj, 'keyTwo.test1', 'zzz');

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few corrections are made.

- You need to advance the object path regardless of creating a child object
- For checking string type, you need to use `typeof`

```js
var obj = {
  keyOne: "foo",
  keyTwo: {
    test1: "baz",
    test2: {
      test21: ["bar"],
    }
  }
}

function setObjectProperty(obj, string, value) {

  var path = string.split('.');
  var currentObj = obj;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < path.length - 1; i++) {
    if (!currentObj[path[i]] || typeof currentObj[path[i]] === 'string') {
      currentObj[path[i]] = {};     
    }
    
     currentObj = currentObj[path[i]];
  }
  currentObj[path[path.length - 1]] = value;
};

setObjectProperty(obj, 'keyOne', 'new');
setObjectProperty(obj, 'keyOne.key.key2', 'newnew');
setObjectProperty(obj, 'keyTwo.test1', 'zzz');

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

The test `currentObj[path[i]] != "string"` seems weird, I think you want to use `typeof` instead.

Inside of your loop, you should be advancing at every step but only creating an object if it does not exists.

Working code:

```
function setObjectProperty(obj, string, value) {
  var path = string.split('.');
  var currentObj = obj;
  for (var i = 0; i < path.length - 1; i++) {
    if (!currentObj[path[i]] || typeof currentObj[path[i]] == "string") {
      currentObj[path[i]] = {};
    }
    currentObj = currentObj[path[i]];
  }
  currentObj[path[path.length - 1]] = value;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```js
const store = {
  keyOne: "foo",
  keyTwo: {
    test1: "baz",
    test2: {
      test21: ["bar"],
    }
  }
}

function getKeys(key) {
  return key.split(".").filter(k => k.length);
}

function assignProps(object, keys, value = null, root = null) {
  root = root || object;
  
  const key = keys.shift();

  if (!key) return root;

  object[key] = keys.length === 0 ? value : {};

  assignProps(object[key], keys, value, root);
}

assignProps(store, getKeys("keyOne.foo.bar"), "baz");
assignProps(store, getKeys("keyTwo.test1.test2"), "value");

console.log(store);
```